# Minimize or Remove traffic transactions from Mapquest Leafelt JS Maps

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapquest

Is there a way to remove or at least `minimize` number of `traffic Transaction` in **MapQuest Leaflet Maps**.

```
if (dir == null) {
        dir = MQ.routing.directions()
           .on('success', function (data) {
               routeSummary(data);

                });

         dir.route({
                 locations: locations,   // is a var of multiple locations (Lat/lon) 
                    options: {
                        avoids: [],
                        disallows: [],
                        destinationManeuverDisplay: false,
                        doReverseGeocode: false,
                        manMaps: false,
                        sideOfStreetDisplay: false
                    }
                });
            }
```

Where **routeSummary** is Defined as

```
function routeSummary(data) {
    if (data && data.route && data.route.distance) 
     {
                var distance = data.route.distance;
                var time = data.route.formattedTime;
     }      
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like it should count any traffic transactions. Is there a url where we can see the application working with the key in question?

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle(reduce/remove) traffic transaction. You have to **disable** a key  `useTraffic: false`

```
               dir.route({
                     locations: locations,   // is a var of multiple locations (Lat/lon) 
                        options: {
                            avoids: [],
                            disallows: [],
                            destinationManeuverDisplay: false,
                            doReverseGeocode: false,
                            manMaps: false,
                            sideOfStreetDisplay: false,
                            useTraffic: false
                        }
                    });
                }
```

> Happy Coding...

Comment: Working... Thanks @HM. This key help us to reduce traffic transaction and now it charges us less.